# Passing StringBuffer value from an outer class to the main

Tags: java, string, class, stringbuffer

I am struggling to pass value of StringBuffer inside the crawler class below to main the class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Crawler
{
 public int threads = 0; 
 public int results = 0; 
 public String output; //this is the string I will pass the buffer value to

public void crawler(String startingURL) 
{ 
 ArrayList<String> listOfPendingURLs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 ArrayList<String> listOfTraversedURLs = new ArrayList<String>(); 

 listOfPendingURLs.add(startingURL); //Add the starting URL to a list named listOfPendingURLs

 while (!listOfPendingURLs.isEmpty() && //while listOfPendingURLs is not empty
    listOfTraversedURLs.size() <= 100) 
   { 
    String urlString = listOfPendingURLs.remove(0); //Remove a URL from listOfPendingURLs

  if (!listOfTraversedURLs.contains(urlString)) //if this URL is not in listOfTraversedURLs
  { 
      listOfTraversedURLs.add(urlString); //Add it to listOfTraversedURLs
      System.out.println("Craw " + urlString); //Display this URL -- change this to display on the panel

      try 
      {
         URL oURL = new URL(urlString);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oURL.openStream()));
         StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
         String lines;
         while ((lines = in.readLine()) != null) 
            strbuf.append(lines); //I want to pass html source code to the main from here

            output = strbuf.toString(); //convert to string
            strbuf.delete(0,strbuf.length());//empty the buffer
            results++;//GUI statistics variable - for future use

         in.close();
      } 

      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

  for (String s: getSubURLs(urlString)) { //Read the page from this URL and for each URL contained in the page
      if (!listOfTraversedURLs.contains(s))
      listOfPendingURLs.add(s); //Add it to listOfPendingURLs if it is not is listOfTraversedURLs
 } //Exit the while loop when the size of S is equal to 100
 } 
 } 
 }

public static ArrayList<String> getSubURLs(String urlString) { 
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

 try { 
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urlString); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(url.openStream()); 
    int current = 0; 

    while (input.hasNext()) 
    { 
      String line = input.nextLine(); 
      current = line.indexOf("http:", current);


    while (current > 0) 
    { 
      int endIndex = line.indexOf("\"", current);

      if (endIndex > 0) { // Ensure that a correct URL is found 
      list.add(line.substring(current, endIndex)); 
      current = line.indexOf("http:", endIndex); 
 } 

 else 
 current = -1;

 } 
 } 
 } 

 catch (Exception ex) 
 { 
   System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage()); 
 } 

 return list; 
 } 
}
```

The main function which I am trying to pass the buffer to can be seen below:

```
public class mainApp
{

public static void main( String args[] )
{ 
  int width = 800;
  int height = 600;
  String title = "Kangaroo";

  int threads = 1;
  int spiders = 20;
  int results = 10325;
  String status = "completed";

  MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(width, height, title, threads, spiders, results, status);
  Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
  TextAnalyser textAnalyser = new TextAnalyser();

  while(width > 1)
  {
  if(frame.startSearch == true)//strt crawling
    {
    //crawler.crawler(frame.url);
    //System.out.println(crawler.source);
    crawler.crawler(frame.url);//start getting html source code
    textAnalyser.analyse(crawler.output);//send the source code to text analyser
    }

  }
}//end main method
}//end class
```

For some reason, it does not read the buffer as null nor displays the source code... Any ideas? I have been trying many variations and none of them seems to work.

Comment: Why not return buffer from method call, rather than have classes that look inside each other?!

Comment: Your code looks very confusing to me. You appear to be throwing out all the content of the StringBuffer (which should be a StringBuilder, no?) with each iteration of the while loop. Are you sure that you want to be doing this?

Comment: I want to throw possibly the whole document and then output it to the main.

Comment: No, you're reading into a StringBuffer, passing that to a String and then discarding both. Why?

Comment: How am I discarding them? I am becoming blind... Sorry mate the deadline is soon and I don't get enough sleep.

Comment: Anything that output held before is gone when it is assigned a new String from your StringBuffer, and so you keep re-writing the output String and are doing nothing with it. Again, this confuses me greatly.

Comment: Ohh I think I know what you mean. I thought if I pass the buffer to the output variable which is global, it will be saved.

Comment: Again, anything that output obtained from the previous iteration of the while loop will be gone, *poof*, with any new iteration of the while loop. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this code, but I'm sure that there are better solutions available. If you need better help, consider explaining your problem and your code better for us. Sorry but your question is very sparse on explanation. A little more effort into your question will likely have a strong effect on getting more fruitful answers.

Comment: In essence, the code keeps crawling a specified domain and what I am trying to do is to output html source code of each link it found which then can be passed to the mainApp class. I am sorry for the vague explanation, I hope it gives you better understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your crawler method to return a string when called, like:

```
public String crawler(String startingURL) {
    String result;
    listOfPendingURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfTraversedURLs = new ArrayList<String>();

    result = "";
    listOfPendingURLs.add(startingURL);
    while (!listOfPendingURLs.isEmpty()
            && listOfTraversedURLs.size() <= 100) {
        String urlString = listOfPendingURLs.remove(0);
        if (!listOfTraversedURLs.contains(urlString)) {
            listOfTraversedURLs.add(urlString);
            // TODO display on panel instead
            System.out.println("Craw " + urlString);
            try {
                URL oURL = new URL(urlString);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(oURL.openStream()));
                StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
                String lines;
                while ((lines = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    strbuf.append(lines);
                }
                result = result + strbuf.toString(); // convert to string
                strbuf.delete(0, strbuf.length());// empty the buffer
                results++;// GUI statistics variable - for future use

                in.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (String s : getSubURLs(urlString)) { // Read the page from
                                                        // this URL and for
                                                        // each URL
                                                        // contained in the
                                                        // page
                if (!listOfTraversedURLs.contains(s))
                    listOfPendingURLs.add(s); // Add it to listOfPendingURLs
                                                // if it is not is
                                                // listOfTraversedURLs
            } 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before mate. It does not output anything. I have no clue why that happens...

Comment: I also placed StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(); and String lines; outside the try and also tried other variatians but still notinh...

Comment: Btw. it works with System.out.println(result); when inside if (!listOfTraversedURLs.contains(urlString))

Comment: Double checked it and it needs to be inside while (!listOfPendingURLs.isEmpty() && //while listOfPendingURLs is not empty
    listOfTraversedURLs.size() <= 100)